# Flutter Text To Speech: Speak several strings subsequently with different SpeechRates

Tags: dart, flutter, async-await, text-to-speech, future

I have a problem with the Flutter Text To Speech package.
When clicking on a FloatingActionButton I would like to speak/play several Strings (with different Speechrates) subsequently. However, when doing so, I can only hear the last string that I have passed onto the function and not the first one.

As you can see in the code below, I have tried to make use of the asynchronus programming (async / await).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter_tts/flutter_tts.dart';

class SpeakerClass extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
  // TODO: implement createState
  return _SpeakerClassState();
  }
}

class _SpeakerClassState extends State<SpeakerClass>{
  String text1 = 'eins';
  String text2 = 'zwei';
  String text3 = 'drei';
  String text4 = 'vier';
  String currentTtsString;
  double ttsSpeechRate1 = 0.5;
  double ttsSpeechRate2 = 1.0;
  double currentSpeechRate;


  Future playTtsString1() async {
    currentTtsString = text1;
    currentSpeechRate = ttsSpeechRate1;
    await runTextToSpeech(currentTtsString, currentSpeechRate);
    return null;
  }

  Future playTtsString2() async {
    currentTtsString = text2;
    currentSpeechRate = ttsSpeechRate2;
    await runTextToSpeech(currentTtsString, currentSpeechRate);
    return null;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: FloatingActionButton (
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      child: Icon(Icons.volume_up, color: Colors.white),
      onPressed: () async {
        await playTtsString1();
        await playTtsString2();
      },
    )
  );
  }

}


Future<void> runTextToSpeech(String currentTtsString, double currentSpeechRate) async {
  FlutterTts flutterTts;
  flutterTts = new FlutterTts();
  await flutterTts.setLanguage("en-GB");
  await flutterTts.setVolume(1.0);
  await flutterTts.setPitch(1.0);
  await flutterTts.isLanguageAvailable("en-GB");
  await flutterTts.setSpeechRate(currentSpeechRate);
  await flutterTts.speak(currentTtsString);
}
```

When pressing the FloatingActionButton I expect the program to first carry out the function playTtsString1 ("eins" with a speed of 0.5) and afterwards the function playTtsString2 ("zwei" with a speed of 1).

However, somehow I can only hear the program saying "zwei". I guess the program is not waiting for the first function "playTtsString1" to be finished and already carries out the second function "playTtsString2". I would really appreciate any help on this matter!

Answer (score 3):

This should now work with the latest flutter_tts version.

You simply need to set awaitSpeakCompletion before the speaking happens.
You can update your run method like so:

```
Future<void> runTextToSpeech(String currentTtsString, double currentSpeechRate) async {
  FlutterTts flutterTts;
  flutterTts = new FlutterTts();
  await flutterTts.awaitSpeakCompletion(true);
  await flutterTts.setLanguage("en-GB");
  await flutterTts.setVolume(1.0);
  await flutterTts.setPitch(1.0);
  await flutterTts.isLanguageAvailable("en-GB");
  await flutterTts.setSpeechRate(currentSpeechRate);
  await flutterTts.speak(currentTtsString);
}
```

Comment: This answer works perfectly. Adding awaitSpeakCompletion works

Answer (score 2):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter_tts/flutter_tts.dart';

class SpeakerClass extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
  // TODO: implement createState
  return _SpeakerClassState();
  }
}

class _SpeakerClassState extends State<SpeakerClass>{
  String text1 = 'eins';
  String text2 = 'zwei';
  String text3 = 'drei';
  String text4 = 'vier';
  String currentTtsString;
  double ttsSpeechRate1 = 0.5;
  double ttsSpeechRate2 = 1.0;
  double currentSpeechRate;

  FlutterTts flutterTts;
  bool bolSpeaking = false;

  Future playTtsString1() async {
    bolSpeaking = true;
    currentTtsString = text1;
    currentSpeechRate = ttsSpeechRate1;
    await runTextToSpeech(currentTtsString, currentSpeechRate);
    return null;
  }

  Future playTtsString2() async {
    bolSpeaking = true;
    currentTtsString = text2;
    currentSpeechRate = ttsSpeechRate2;
    await runTextToSpeech(currentTtsString, currentSpeechRate);
    return null;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: FloatingActionButton (
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      child: Icon(Icons.volume_up, color: Colors.white),
      onPressed: () async {
        // Play String 1
        await playTtsString1();

        // Check String 1 Finish
        new Future.delayed(new Duration(milliseconds: 100), () async {
            // loop until bolSpeaking = false
            while (bolSpeaking) {
              await Thread.sleep(100);
            }

            // play String 2
            await playTtsString2();
        }
      },
    )
  );
  }
}


Future<void> runTextToSpeech(String currentTtsString, double currentSpeechRate) async {
  flutterTts = new FlutterTts();
  await flutterTts.setLanguage("en-GB");
  await flutterTts.setVolume(1.0);
  await flutterTts.setPitch(1.0);
  await flutterTts.isLanguageAvailable("en-GB");
  await flutterTts.setSpeechRate(currentSpeechRate);

  flutterTts.setCompletionHandler(() {
    setState(() {
      // The following code(s) will be called when the TTS finishes speaking
      bolSpeaking = false;
    });
  });

  flutterTts.speak(currentTtsString);
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer man! Unfortunately, it still does not work as expected. I edited the code as you have suggested, however, I can only hear the second text and not the first text when pressing the button.

Comment: that means flutterTts.speak() returns immediately after call, without waiting the speaking to complete

Comment: ok, I remember, there is a setCompletionHandler, I'll update the answe

Comment: Pls. check the updated answer.  I may have made mistakes in the code, i.e. the [position] of some codes may not be correct.  In my original codes, I did not [NEW] a [flutterTts] every time I want to speak a string, instead, my flutterTts is a static variable in another dart file, and only initialized ONCE in my whole app.  So I'm not sure if this variable is to be initialized many times, will the flutterTts.setCompletionHandler still work or not!

Comment: Really thanks for your help! Somehow the code still doesn't work. It seems like there are quite a few mistakes inside of it.